# Функция запоминания input при выборе адреса на yandex map

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api, input, localstorage

На сайте есть функция выбора адреса путем тыка и определения геопозиции на карте yandex map

```
$(document).ready(function(){
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
var  myInput = document.getElementById("input-result"),
    myPlacemark,
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.862267, 48.372041],
        zoom: 13
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

// Слушаем клик на карте.
myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var coords = e.get('coords');

    // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
    if (myPlacemark) {
        myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
    }
    // Если нет – создаем.
    else {
        myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
        myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
            getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
        });
    }
    getAddress(coords);
});

// Создание метки.
function createPlacemark(coords) {
    return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
        iconCaption: 'поиск...'
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
        draggable: true
    });
}

// Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
function getAddress(coords) {
    myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
    ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
        var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
            address = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();

        myPlacemark.properties
            .set({
                // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                iconCaption: [
                    // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                    firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                    // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                    firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                balloonContent: address
            });
        myInput.value = address;
    });
}
}
});
```

Как сделать так чтобы сохранялась запись в input с ID input-result при перезагрузке путем local Storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ymaps.ready(init);
        function init() {
            var  myInput = document.getElementById("input-result"),
                myPlacemark,
                myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    center: [55.862267, 48.372041],
                    zoom: 13
                }, {
                    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
                });

// Слушаем клик на карте.
            myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
                var coords = e.get('coords');

                // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
                if (myPlacemark) {
                    myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
                }
                // Если нет – создаем.
                else {
                    myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
                    // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
                    myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
                        getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
                    });
                }
                getAddress(coords);
            });

// Создание метки.
            function createPlacemark(coords) {
                return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
                    iconCaption: 'поиск...'
                }, {
                    preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
                    draggable: true
                });
            }

// Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
            function getAddress(coords) {
                myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
                ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
                    var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                        address = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();

                    myPlacemark.properties
                        .set({
                            // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                            iconCaption: [
                                // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                                firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                                // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                                firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                            ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                            // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                            balloonContent: address
                        });
                    myInput.value = address;
                    localStorage.setItem('value', address); // При вызове функции (которая срабатываем при нажатии на карте) записываем данные в localstorage
                });
            }
            if(localStorage.getItem('value')){ // При выполнении функции init, если есть данные в localstorage, то...
                myInput.value = localStorage.getItem('value'); // Вставляем значение в input
            }
        }
    });
```